# Display a audio waveform using C#

Tags: c#, audio, waveform

I've already searched at Stackoverflow and google, but haven't found what I'm looking for.
So far I got the audio raw data(WAV File) and I want to visualize it.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\tada.wav", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);
        char[] data = new char[4];
        long fsize;
        long wfxSize;
        long dataSize;
        WaveFormatEx wfx;

        //RIFF
        reader.Read(data, 0, 4);

        fsize = reader.ReadInt32();

        //WAVE
        reader.Read(data, 0, 4);

        //FMT
        reader.Read(data, 0, 4);
        wfxSize = reader.ReadInt32();

        byte[] wfxBuffer = new byte[wfxSize];
        reader.Read(wfxBuffer, 0, (int)wfxSize);
        wfx = new WaveFormatEx(wfxBuffer);

        //DATA
        reader.Read(data, 0, 4);
        dataSize = reader.ReadInt32();
        byte[] dataBuff = new byte[dataSize];
        reader.Read(dataBuff, 0, (int)dataSize);
        reader.Close();

        //Visualize the data...
    }
```

I know I need to convert the raw data into samples and then check for the peak for each sample and draw lines, but I really don't know how to do it(except for the drawing).

Comment: As Gigasoft founder, we have a solution that simplifies this need and provides example code to play and chart the wav data much like adobe audition or nero wave editor.  See our small 18meg v8 [c# charting demo](http://www.gigasoft.com) and review demo example 123. The download also includes WPF and MFC exes and source code to show the necessary learning curve. This example does not rely upon dependent libraries and shows the minimal code to visualize and play a wav.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Visualize the data..**. Wow! You should check out the [WAV file spec here](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html) and [perhaps here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) and then re-think whether this is something you actually want to tackle. (The second link is actually a better, more streamlined overview. Take a look at the data section to see if it's something you want to work with.)

Don't get me wrong. Maybe this is exactly what you want to do, and it might be fun. You should just know what you're getting into!

Also, here's a [Code Project component](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/wavecontrol.aspx) that you could use outright or look at for ideas.

Comment: By "Visualize the data" I meant display a simple waveform based on amp, not 3D Visualization...  
Anyway this code project component is really helpful, thanks.

Comment: 2 of 3 links are not valid

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [NAudio library](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).

See is the [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnFoVuOVrUQ) on how to use NAudio to display waveforms.